# MongoDB & MySQL relationships in jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

Let's begin with some plain code. I have two following models. 
First is using MySQL:

```
class Phrase extends \Eloquent {

    public function positions()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('Position');
    }

    public function getIdAttribute($id)
    {
        return (int) $id;
    }
}
```

and second is using MongoDB:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class Position extends Eloquent {

    protected $collection = 'positions';
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    public function phrase()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Phrase');
    }
}
```

In my controller I want to get phrase positions:

```
Phrase::find(1)->positions
```

which is generating query

```
positions.find({"positions.phrase_id":1}, [])
```

instead of

```
positions.find({"phrase_id":1}, [])
```

How I can fix it? The problem is inside HasMany method (http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#_hasMany).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the functionality by creating my own function inside the model

```
class Phrase extends \Eloquent {

    public function positions()
    {
        return Position::where('phrase_id', '=', (int) $this->id)->get();
        return $this->hasMany('Position');
    }
}


$positions = Phrase::find(1)->positions();
```

Anyway, this solution is not a great replacement, because it's breaking convention. Third programmers may not know how to use this relationship.

Answer (score 1):

use this trait in both models and u can use basic relationships

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;

class User extends Model 
{
   protected $connection = "mysql" ;

   use HybridRelations ;

}

class Orders extends Model 
{
   protected $connection = "mongo" ;

   use HybridRelations ;
}
```